# Transactions to authorize/revoke READ access to transaction initiator's assets in Hyperledger Composer ACL

Tags: hyperledger-composer

At the Hyperledger Composer github, they give an example of a conditional ACL script with an optional transaction clause. In the example they provide, it's  operations access to the asset owner and INITIATOR of the transaction.

rule SampleConditionalRuleWithTransaction {
    description: "Description of the ACL rule"
    participant(m): "org.example.SampleParticipant"
    operation: READ, CREATE, UPDATE
    resource(v): "org.example.SampleAsset"
    transaction(tx): "org.example.SampleTransaction"
    condition: (v.owner.getIdentifier() == m.getIdentifier())
    action: ALLOW
}

What if I want the 'recipient' of the transaction, to be given READ rights to the transaction initiator's assets? For example, a participant transaction that authorizes or revokes a regulators read rights to the transaction initiators (owner/participant's) assets.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial which covers ACLs in more detail? https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/next/tutorials/acl-trading.html  Note that this doc is in the 'next' stream of the documentation i.e. Composer v0.18.*, but it should work fine with composer v0.16.* in the 'latest' stream.

Comment: I hadn't seen this. The permissions examples in your link don't address what I'm looking for, quite. I know I can set up permissions that are more persistent for a regulator participant, but wanted a permission that is granted and revoked through a transaction by the asset owner/participant. Thank you very much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

In an asset definition  you can have a field, allowed_viewer field and based on that you can have define rules to view the asset

Example 
In the cto file,

```
asset Commodity identified by tradingSymbol {
  o String tradingSymbol
  o String description
  o String mainExchange
  o Double quantity
  o Trader[] allowed_viewer
  --> Trader owner
}
```

In acl file

```
rule R1a_Traderview {
  description: "Everyone in allowed_viewer can view"
  participant(p): "org.example.trading.Trader"
  operation: READ
  resource(r): "org.example.trading.Commodity"
  condition: (r.allowed_viewer.indexOf(p.getIdentifier())>=0)
  action: ALLOW
}
```